# selenium scrape multiple attributes within a block at the same time

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a webpage follow the pattern:

```
<a class="card cardlisting0"  href="abc/def/gh.com">
     <div class="contentWrapper"> 
       <div class="card-content">
         <time datetime="2020-05-31">3 hours ago</time>
       </div>
     </div>
</a>

<a class="card cardlisting1"  href="ijk/lmn/op.com">
     <div class="contentWrapper">
       <div class="card-content">
         <time datetime="2020-04-30">20200430</time>
       </div>
     </div>
</a>

...
```

And I want to scrape the href and date time attribute in pairs: [abc/def/gh.com,2020-05-31], [ijk/lmn/op.com, 2020-04-30]

How can I realize this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

t='''<a class="card cardlisting0"  href="abc/def/gh.com">
     <div class="contentWrapper"> 
       <div class="card-content">
         <time datetime="2020-05-31">3 hours ago</time>
       </div>
     </div>
</a>

<a class="card cardlisting1"  href="ijk/lmn/op.com">
     <div class="contentWrapper">
       <div class="card-content">
         <time datetime="2020-04-30">20200430</time>
       </div>
     </div>
</a>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(t,"lxml")

aTags=soup.select('a')

data=[]

for aTag in aTags:
    timeTag=aTag.select_one('time')
    data.append([aTag.get('href'),timeTag['datetime']])

print(data)
```

Instead of `t` you can use the response from selenium.

Output:

```
[['abc/def/gh.com', '2020-05-31'], ['ijk/lmn/op.com', '2020-04-30']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_element_by_xpath()` and `get_attribute()` functions using Python, as follows:

```
# for the hrefs
urls = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "card cardlisting0")]')]

# for the datetimes
dates = [time_element.get_attribute('datetime') for time_element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a//time')]
```